# Collection <NSCFSet: 0x1b0b30> was mutated while being enumerated. How to determine which set?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ipad

I'm doing a bunch of core data inserts and after 20k or so inserts with saves every 1-2k I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <NSCFSet: 0x1b0b30> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

I'm trying to figure out which NSSet is causing this. I've done a search and the only NSSets in my code are the autogenerated ones that handle the Core Data relationships.

I'm using NSXMLParser and for each element found creating a new entity (if a matching one doesn't already exist).

So I will create a state entity and then populate all the city entities and then do a save. This means that a state's NSSet *cities is getting added to but I don't see why you can't do that.

Comment: Are you doing this on a background thread? Is there perhaps any operation being performed on the entities on the main thread? Without a little code, it's going to be difficult to diagnose this, but in my limited experience, this exception occurs frequently when changing a set that is being iterated over, even if the operations are in separate threads.

Comment: Yes this is on a background thread. My main thread is just showing an UIAlertView with a spinner/message. I will check to make sure that my underlying UITableViews aren't trying to refresh while the insert is going on though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` and grab a backtrace.   That should indicate what is enumerating during mutation.